# Background bigger than the div

Tags: css

I have a div :

```
<div class="titre_section" id="identity_section_titre_section">Identité du déclarant</div>
```

i need to put a background outside the div to apply a bigger height than the div

for the moment i have :

```
.titre_section {
        position: relative;

        @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
            top: -2em;
        }
        top: -5em;
        left: -2em;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-family: $titre_section-font-family;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 0.25px;
        color: $form-dark-color;
        background: url("/custom/images/titre_section_rectangle.png") no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

here the result :

[image]

i tried to make this in order to modify the height of the background :

```
.titre_section::before{
            content: "";
            background: url("/custom/images/titre_section_rectangle.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
```

but it's not working i don't see the background.

the result need to be like. i can't edit the html because we use zend form system

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used :pseudo element to add the border effect in the left

```css
.titre_section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 0 10px 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2cfc7;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:20px
}

.titre_section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #bb8f29;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titre_section" id="identity_section_titre_section">Identité du déclarant</div>
```

Comment: was happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example using `position: absolute` to ensure that the background doesn't take up space, and `z-index` to ensure that the background is behind the content.

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">Identité du déclarant</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `:before` pseudoelement needs width and height to be set. You can set either of them to `100%` if the element is `position: absolute` and the parent is `position: relative` if you want the dimensions to be relative to the parent.